# How to block spammers from using my public email api

Tags: security

I am working on a web application which allows users to share stuff on a web-page by clicking on an 'email to friend' link; similar to what extole is doing here 
http://www.american-giant.com/mens-heavyweight-full-zip-hooded-sweatshirt-product.html

on this page if you click on the email icon near "REFER & GET $15", you will see a pop-up where you can enter your own email and a friends email and can edit the subject of the email. When you click send the data is sent to the backend as json. They are using a plain simple url to do this i.e. http://refer.american-giant.com/v2/share.

The problem for me is that somehow spammers got hold of my url (can't mention here) and now they are using it to spam others by using some sort of a script. What I did is I placed a check in the backend api to block an ip if more than 5 share requests originate from it, but it seems that the spammers have a lots of ips (more than 30,000 from what I counted in my logs) so they are still able to send lots of email. One possible solution is to use a captcha to thwart the spamming script. But I am curious that how extole is doing it. They aren't using any captchas; and they are famous too, so it is unlikely that spammers don't know about their publicly accessible api. Can any one shed some light on this?

Note: 
1. I am using a third party email service to send the emails.
2. Users are not required to sign in as this defeats the purpose of sharing on a simple website
3. Users can edit the subject and body, thus these are sent to the api call and this is what allows the spammers to abuse the api with their own stuff.

Comment: By "users" you mean "signed in users"?

Comment: I'm not voting to close, but given that the focus of the question is "security," and you're not showing us code (which undermines the scope of the question being a 'programming question'), I'd suggest that this *might* be a better fit for [security.se], though please check their "[What questions can I ask here?](http://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)" guidance first.

Comment: How exactly are they spamming other users? Does your web api allow senders to specify subject and message body? Or are they simply sending a bunch of referrals to your actual pages?

Comment: 1. Users are not signed in users
2. Yes, the api allows to specify from, to address and a subject and body which is a requirement (so that users can edit them)

Comment: So what you're describing is web page that anyone can use to e-mail anyone else, without authentication so that it's "open".  Sorry, but without authentication of some sort, there's no way to secure this, short of inspecting every e-mail before it goes out.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about security. Maybe ask at [security.se].

Comment: @WilliamWalseth Yes, you are right, its open. Can I infer that all other services out there which are also open are also susceptible to abuse by spammers and that I should definitely add a captcha?

Comment: Yes, they would all be susceptible to it.  Captcha isn't security in my book.